# Novel where the protagonist has many first names?

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to find a teen sci-fi novel I read back in the UK in the mid-2000s. It was paperback and the cover design seemed old at the time.

The protagonist had a large number of first names she was referred to throughout:

- **Cindy** (the name most used by the rest of the characters)
- **Lucinda** (her full name)
- **Lucy** (only used by her father)
- **Cin** (protagonist only uses it for herself, and she mentions her mother forbid her from using it as a nickname)
- **Cinnamon** (a man met on her journey claims that Cindy is too modern of a name to use safely)

The plot involves a group of teens, including Cindy, waking up from cryosleep in a very well supplied bunker, sometime in the distant future.

Cindy watches a video from her father which has very much has a 'if you're watching this I am dead and have failed to save your sister' message.

The group leave the bunker to find a society that all technology (beyond the industrial revolution?) is now illegal, punishable by death (I think there's an execution where they pour soil in a man's mouth?).

Eventually, one of the teenage boys succeeds in some sort of a revolution, reintroducing technology to society, but Cindy decides instead to return to the bunker by herself to live and deletes the access codes(?) to prevent the other teens from accessing the bunker too.

The novel ends with a video triggering on the deletion of the codes from the person who put the teens in cryosleep, revealing that Cindy was behaving exactly as they expected her to, abandoning the group for a bunker of modern conveniences.

I think the novel had a *really* generic title -'the end of the world' sort of thing.